# How to resolve the 'Argument is not assignable to parameter' error when using CASL with Prisma in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma, casl

This is the [reference](https://casl.js.org/v6/en/package/casl-prisma) which I follow to try CASL with prisma. However I got an error.
This is my code:

```
import { user } from '@prisma/client';
import { PureAbility, AbilityBuilder, subject } from '@casl/ability';
import { createPrismaAbility, PrismaQuery, Subjects } from '@casl/prisma';

type AppAbility = PureAbility<
  [
    string,
    Subjects<{
      user: user;
    }>,
  ],
  PrismaQuery
>;
const { can, build } = new AbilityBuilder<AppAbility>(createPrismaAbility);

can('read', 'user', { id: 1 });

const ability = build();
ability.can('read', 'user');

console.log(ability.can('read', subject('user', { id: 1 }) as any)); // work
console.log(ability.can('read', subject('user', { id: 1 }))); // error here
```

Error:

> Argument of type '{ id: number; } & ForcedSubject<"user">' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'Subjects<{ user: user; }>'.   Type '{
> id: number; } & ForcedSubject<"user">' is not assignable to type
> 'Model<user, "user">'.
> Type '{ id: number; } & ForcedSubject<"user">' is missing the following properties from type 'user': googleId, email, password,
> tfaStatus, and 7 more.ts(2345)

Image: [image]
Any solutions or tutorials would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I think this is intentional and you can't do this. You have to pass the full object. See https://github.com/stalniy/casl/issues/778

Wrong answer:

The `{ id: 1 }` passed into subject needs to be type `user`:

`ability.can('read', subject('user', { id: 1 }) as user));`

This is why `as any` works as well. This is *probably* an oversight in the library, as it's not actually of type `user`.